# android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

My App is voice streaming between two android phones.

this code is listening part(server side)

but i face this error

android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException

i put the cat logs.have a look

please give me your best help.

thanks in advance.

code :

```
    package com.example.encryptechatresiving;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button receiveButton,stopButton;
private TextView recive;
private EditText port;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private AudioTrack speaker;


private int sampleRate = 44100;      
private int channelConfig =  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       

private boolean status = true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    receiveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.receive_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    recive= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receive_label);
    //recive.setText("Created...!");
    receiveButton.setOnClickListener(receiveListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
    //receiveButton.setText("Start Reciving...!");
    //stopButton.setText("Stop Reciving...!");
    port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //port.setText("1234");

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    sampleRate =Integer.parseInt( audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
}


private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        status = false;
        //recive.setText("Recoder Stop...!");
        speaker.release();
        Log.d("VR","Speaker released");

    }

};


private final OnClickListener receiveListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;
       // recive.setText(" before Start ");

        startReceiving();

    }

};

public void startReceiving() {

    Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                int port_num=Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port_num);
                Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                int minBufSize =256; //AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //256

                speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,16000,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
               //AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
                speaker.play();
              // recive.setText("hear anything...?");
                while(status == true) {
                    try {


                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                        //reading content from packet
                        buffer=packet.getData();
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                        //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                        speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                        Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");

                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("VR","IOException");
                    }
                }


            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e("VR", "SocketException");
            }


        }

    });
    receiveThread.start();
}

}
```

Logs:

```
    05-23 22:56:10.646: D/VR(789): Socket Created
05-23 22:56:10.746: W/dalvikvm(789): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-77
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6452)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at com.example.encryptechatresiving.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:113)
05-23 22:56:10.807: E/AndroidRuntime(789):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-23 22:56:10.897: W/ActivityManager(291):   Force finishing activity com.example.encryptechatresiving/.MainActivity
05-23 22:56:10.906: W/WindowManager(291): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast must be in UI thread .

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Talking....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are accessing

> port.getText().toString()

from separate **non-UI thread** which is wrong that's why you are getting this exception. So, try to access it from main thread.

```
//accessing it from ui-thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           int port_num=Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
       }
  });
```

**Edit**: Test the edited code if again you are getting **syntax error** as mentioned by you in your comments

```
private int port_num;

public void startReceiving() {

    Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        port_num=Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());                           
                    }
                });



                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port_num);
                Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                int minBufSize =256; //AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //256

                speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,16000,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
               //AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
                speaker.play();
              // recive.setText("hear anything...?");
                while(status == true) {
                    try {


                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                        //reading content from packet
                        buffer=packet.getData();
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                        //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                        speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                        Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");

                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("VR","IOException");
                    }
                }


            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e("VR", "SocketException");
            }


        }

    });
    receiveThread.start();
}
```

Comment: can you put the all source code not just one part? when i change it i see another error (not runtime error)

Comment: syntax error.it says close the bracket.so i do it but dosen't work...!

Comment: no syntax error. but still the same log cat. see in first post

Comment: what if you put your whole code inside runOnUiThread? Still you are getting exception?

Comment: tnx.solve the problem by puting the whole code inside the runUiThread.i can't give you +1 why.?

Comment: @Ryan10- No problem if you don't want to give me +1

Comment: i want to give you +1 but Vote Up requires 15 reputation that i don't have that much. you solved my problem of course i want to give you +1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a `Toast` message from a background `Thread`. so replace

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Talking....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Running background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This runs your `Toast` on UI `Thread`.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. i put the wrong source code. will you cheek the first post again?

Comment: can you tell at which line you are getting the error.

Comment: in startReceiving method and after Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");

Comment: May be problem is due to the audio track, try to play the audio track from the UI Thread.

Comment: do you think that i can put the whole code inside the                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}  method??

Comment: not the whole method just  speaker.play();
and i am not sure about that.